# Associate IdentityUser to an Entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is the IdentityUser subclass, and a simple entity. How can the IdentityUser be referenced within the Entity class? This application is using Entity Framework Core.

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
}
```

**Entity.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public int EntityId { get; set; }

        /* What belongs here to associate to a user? */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention-over-configuration way would be:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

And the following is optional, you can omit it if you don't need to get all `Entities` for an user.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```